# How to prevent ShellFolder.getFolderColumns(...) from crashing a lot

Tags: java, file-io, file

I'm using the secret hidden ShellFolder class in Java. It has a nice method called getFolderColumns which gives you access to some nice data about the file.

Problem is that a lot of files crash it with :

> Exception in thread
>   "pool-1-thread-2445"
>   java.lang.InternalError: Unable to
>   bind C:\Windows\System32\zonedon.reg
>   to parent  at
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$4.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:400)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$4.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:385)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker.invoke(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:523)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.invoke(ShellFolder.java:399)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.invoke(ShellFolder.java:385)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getIShellFolder(Win32ShellFolder2.java:384)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$17.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:1068)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$17.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:1066)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>    at
>   sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:492)
>    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

You also can't catch this and resume as it throws a UncaughtException.
I noticed that JFileChooser also uses this method but I can't seem to find its prevention/protection from these type of crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getFolderColumns method only works for folders. So cache the column info(so you know the column position) and you can still get the column data needed from files. I haven't seen a case where the columns on folders are different from files.

Oh just to note that that this method is only good on windows.