# I want to access a file without changing its last access date in java

Tags: java, windows, symlink

I want to programmatically read a file on windows machine but without changing its lastAccess date as these files are created using a sym link and if I change the last access date of these files, a program will actually download these files later which I don't want

How can I do that in java?

Comment: Have you tried something, encountered any issue?

Comment: A program will download the file because it was *accessed* without being *modified*? That's just plain... *wrong*.

Comment: I was able to achieve the same using googles jcifs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used google jcifs connector and was able to access the file without modifying access date

Answer (score 0):

Get the last access time, read the file, reset the last access time.

See [Java set accessed date on file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256354/java-set-accessed-date-on-file).